# H-closed = compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

This is an exercise from Herrlich's *Axiom of choice*, and I'm a bit struggling with it.

I want to show that a topological space $X$ is compact Hausdorff if and only if it is H-closed and regular.

NB : I don't know what the convention is, but here H-closed means that for any Hausdorff $Y$ such that there is an (continuous) embedding $X\to Y$, then the image of $X$ is closed.

I managed to show the "compact$\implies$ H-closed" part, through the filter-compact characterization of compact spaces; but the other part I couldn't do.

I can't see how to use H-closed ness to prove that $X$ has the Borel-Lebesgue property, and so I think that using the filter characterization would be the best; but given a filter $\mathcal{F}$ with no cluster point, I don't see what space I could embed $X$ in that would give me nice things. Any indications ?

Comment: By embedding do you mean a homeomorphic embedding?

Comment: compact implies H-closed needs no filters, just the observation that any compact subspace of a Hausdorff space is closed.

Comment: @user254665 He does.

Comment: @Henno : well I don't know much about general topology, I only know a bit about metric spaces, so I didn't know if this property was true in general (so I tried to prove it again, using filters)

Comment: It is true in general spaces, which is part of the inspiration for the whole notion of $H$-closedness.

Comment: If you can show that regular plus H-closed implies  Tychonoff (completely regular) then you can use the result that a  Tychonoff space with weight $W$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of the compact Hausdorff space $[0,1]^W$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that $X$ is $H$-closed iff every open cover has a finite subfamily whose union is dense, then use regularity to go to compactness.

See [my note here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/15.htm) for a proof of this.

Another way is to use the filter characterisation of $H$-closedness:

$X$ is $H$-closed iff every open filter $\mathscr{F}$ of $X$ (i.e. a filter in the poset of open sets of $X$) has an adherence point. (i.e. $\bigcap \{\overline{F}: F \in \mathscr{F} \} \neq \emptyset$).

Then compact implies $H$-closed is then also clear (And compact plus Hausdorff implies regular) (as the closures form a FIP family). And if $X$ is $H$-closed and regular, take any open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $X$. If it has no finite subcover, refine it (using regularity) by a cover of regular closed sets having no finite subcover as well, and then consider the open filter generated by the complements of finite unions of subfamilies of that family...