# a question about finer topology

Tags: general-topology

A Hausdorff topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ is called *‎‎$‎H‎$‎-closed*   if it is closed in any Hausdorff space, which contains $X$ as a subspace.

I ‎want ‎to ‎prove ‎that ‎‎‎the topological property ‎of‎ ‎$‎H‎$‎-closed is established for finer topologies, in other words ‎‎$‎(X, ‎\tau_2)‎$ ‎is ‎‎$‎H‎$‎- closed‎‎ and $‎‎ \tau_1‎‎\subset‎  ‎\tau_2‎$. But I do not know if my method is correct or not.

I assume ‎‎$‎(X ,‎\tau_1)‎$‎‎  is a ‎‎$‎H‎$‎- closed space ‎and‎  $‎‎\tau_1‎‎\subset‎  ‎\tau_2‎$.‎
‎
According to the definition,  space ‎‎$‎(X,‎\tau_2)‎$‎‎ can be ‎imbedded‎ in a Hausdorff space $ ‎‎(Y, ‎\tau)‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎, t‎hat ‎is, ‎‎$‎‎  ‎\tau_2 = \tau_‎\mid_{X}  ‎‎‎$‎.‎‎
How can I ‎use from ‎$‎H‎$‎-clossed ‎property ‎of ‎$‎(X ,‎\tau_1)‎$   ‎ ‎to say that ‎there is ‎a‎ ‎Hausdorff‎ topology ‎‎$‎\tau‎^{‎*‎}‎‎‎$  so ‎that‎ ‎$‎‎\tau‎^{*} ‎\subset ‎\tau‎‎‎‎$ and ‎$‎‎\tau‎^{‎*‎}‎_‎\mid_X = ‎\tau_1‎$‎‎‎?‎‎

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

In the situation where $(X,\tau_1)$ is (Hausdorff and) $H$-closed, and $(X,\tau_2)$ would be $H$-closed and we have a proper inclusion $\tau_1 \subsetneq \tau_2$, then $(X,\tau_2)$ cannot be semiregular, by the theorem

> $X$ is minimal Hausdorff iff $X$ is $H$-closed and semiregular.

and the fact that, by definition, $(X,\tau_2)$ is not minimal Hausdorff.

For useful implications the inclusion goes the wrong way: $(X,\tau_1)$ $H$-closed means that every $\tau_1$-open cover has a finite subset whose closures cover $X$. But this says not too much about $\tau_2$-open covers.

A possible example of this situation actually occurring is $X=[0,1]$ in $\tau_1$ the usual topology and $\tau_2$ the topology generated by $\{\mathbb{Q}\} \cup \tau_1$ which is a well-known example of a non-compact $H$-closed space. But there might be a counterexample too.

Comment: According to the above, the topological property $H$-closed does not exist for a finer topology. It seems that it does not exist for coarser topology ?

Comment: @adin that's not what I said, I just noted some restrictions. I even gave an example of the situation..

Comment: Do you mean  my problem solving method  is wrong?                                     
Sorry I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: @adin I indeed don't think your approach will give a proof. See Cameron's trivial counterexample..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, finer topologies won't necessarily be H-closed. For example, suppose $\langle X,\tau_1\rangle$ is a topological space that is H-closed, such that $X$ is infinite, and consider the discrete topology $\tau_2$ on $X.$ Since regular Hausdorff H-closed spaces are compact, then $\langle X,\tau_2\rangle$ cannot be H-closed, as the open cover singletons has no finite subcover. However, we trivially have $\tau_1\subset\tau_2.$

Comment: can you tel me which book refer to "regular Hausdorff H-closed spaces are compact "?Thank you.

Comment: @adin See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202773/h-closed-compact